# How to get text from user on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, window, android-edittext

How to make a window dialog that contain only an EditText and that popup like an alert to get Text from user under Android please.?

I've already checked this [Get text from an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612069/get-text-from-an-edittext)

Comment: mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
string value=mEdit.getText().toString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setMessage("Message");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
  String value = input.getText();
  // Do something with value!
  }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // Canceled.
  }
});

alert.show();
```

Comment: I also found this , but don't know how to integrate it in Activity ?

Comment: is **this** the current Activity ?

Comment: You can add it inside the Activity. Add it in an onclick event if you want to show this dialog to a user on click of something.

Comment: I have an error on *new AlertDialog.Builder(this);* and *new EditText(this);* lines ?? how to fix it ? using getApplicationContext() ?

Comment: "the constructor of AlertDialog is undefined" same for EditText.

Comment: Seems like you are calling this inside an inner class. The parameter is actually the context. Try `YourActivityName.this' instead of `this`

Comment: I found it : *NameActivity.this* in the place of *this*

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

in your manifest for the activity containing the `EditText` and call `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` before `setContentView`.

This should show the activity in a alert dialog.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 activity_login.xml // place inside layout folder


 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="clickme"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
   </Button>

   </RelativeLayout>



   dialog_box.xml /// layout for dialog,Place it inside drawable folder

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff" >

   <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="40dip"
     android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DialogBox"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
   </LinearLayout>

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/txtview"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/linearlayout"
     android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
     android:text="Enter E-mail Address"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:textSize="14sp"
     android:textStyle="bold" />

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtFEmail"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtview"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="E-mail"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >
  </EditText>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/edtFEmail"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSaveDialog"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancelDialog"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16dip" />
       </LinearLayout>

       </RelativeLayout>





 LoginActivity .java

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

Context ctx;

EditText edtFEmailDialog;

Button btnShowDialog, btnCancelDialog, btnSaveDialog;

Dialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    ctx = this;

    init();

    btnSaveDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String sfemail = edtFEmailDialog.getText().toString();
            if (edtFEmailDialog.getText().toString().equals("")
                     ||   edtFEmailDialog.getText().toString().equals("null")) {
                                   edtFEmailDialog.requestFocus();
                edtFEmailDialog.setError("Please Enter E-mail Address");
                return;
            }

            Toast.makeText(ctx, edtFEmailDialog.getText().toString(), 1000)
                    .show();

        }
    });

    btnCancelDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            edtFEmailDialog.setText("");
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    btnShowDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}

public void init() {

    dialog = new Dialog(LoginActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_box);

    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    btnShowDialog = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnDialog);

    btnCancelDialog = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelDialog);
    btnSaveDialog = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveDialog);
    edtFEmailDialog = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtFEmail);

}


    }
  cheers guys
```